# Rails Query to find attribute with single quote in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been developing a rails application and want to get the `id` of one of my entries in table named DocumentType.

My problem is that I don't know how to do a query over an attribute which value has single quote in it.

To be more clear I want to get the `id` of the document_type named "Décision d'engagement".

I tried these:

```
DocumentType.where(name: "Décision d'engagement").first.id
DocumentType.where(name: "Décision d\'engagement").first.id
DocumentType.where(name: "Décision d''engagement").first.id
DocumentType.find_by(name: "Décision d\'engagement").id
DocumentType.find_by(name: "Décision d''engagement").id
```

None of those works, the only way I found to get a result is to use a LIKE query, but I'm not totally satisfied with this solution.

```
DocumentType.where("name LIKE ?", "%engagement%").first.id
```

If any of you have a solution I would be grateful.

By the way I'm using Rails 4.2 with a Sqlite DB for development purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: `DocumentType.where(name: "Décision d'engagement").first.id` would be correct. Perhaps the error lies in the "Decision" part--specifically the "e" with the accent.

Comment: Agreed, tried and worked on PostgreSQL. Encoding issue?

Comment: Try copying and pasting the title directly from a database GUI like Navicat or pgAdmin. It's probably either the é, or perhaps the apostrophe is a smart quote (e.g., ’)?

Comment: Or perhaps there is a leading or trailing space in the name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the accent is not involved in this problem. Cause query over "Note de Vérification et de Validation" (DocumentType.where(name: "Note de Vérification et de Validation").first.id) works but query for "Rapport d’audit" doesn't work either.

Comment: And the type of apostrophe can't be involve too, cause i copy the field from the fixtures when it comes from. So it must have exactly the same characters.